# Gradle: Rerun task on fail?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

We use gradle to run test with QF-Test. Every QF-Test file is executeted with a "exec task". The exit code of "qftest" is the test result (0=Passed, 1=Warning, 2= ...). Now we are searching for a way to rerun a failed task.

Is there a possibility to auto rerun a failed task in gradle?

Comment: You can write your own task (type) that calls `project.exec()` as often as it needs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible - each task can be executed only once during one build. You can create another task with type `Test` (or QF-Test) configured similarly except that it will run only tests that failed during execution of the first task.

Your idea may look appealing for a moment but it creates a lot of problems. Starting with 'how to report those test results?'

Comment: Thanks. I will try your solution. The idea was to report them as two runs (failed and passed). We just want to see, that one run passed.

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/test-retry-gradle-plugin might help.